# DNS Lookups 1 / TCP Connects 1 while loop is 100 httpWebRequest

Tags: c#, tcp, dns, httpwebrequest

Hello i have a httpwebrequest (C# visual script) that is visting an Url and im analyzing it with a http sniffer. I'm running the script for 100 times but there is only 1 time a DNS lookup and TCP connect?

I'm trying to get it connected as many times as i set the loop, how can i achieve this, do i need to change things in the header section??

Thnx in advance.

```
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");

                request.Method = "GET";
                request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
                request.Timeout = 10000;
                request.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;
```

Im not getting an error it does run the full 100 times but it only connects DNS and TCP 1 time according to my analyzer. And i would like to have it connected the whole loop, is this possible??

Comment: What is your code, what have you tried? Be more spesific.

Comment: (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
               
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
                request.Timeout = 10000;
                request.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;

Comment: Update your question, what is your code? What do you get an error? Give people more information.

Comment: and im a beginner so im not a professional :)

Comment: Writing a good question doesn't require being a professional. Read Jon Skeet's blog post http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this behaviour is due to connection reuse and DNS hostname caching. In order to see repeatative DNS requests you will have to use differnt hosts for every requests or just wait out DNS TTL (Time To Live) timeout so the DNS cache entry expires.
TCP connect is more easy to handle as it will happen each time if you set request.KeepAlive = false; This should close the connection after request is complete.